# Endpoints stopped working on latest deployment - Appenine

Tags: google-app-engine, oauth-2.0, google-cloud-endpoints

I am using cloud endpoints and Java appengine.  On my latest deployment Oauth2 authorization stopped working.  Seems as though my existing endpoints are working minus Oauth, and my updated endpoints are not deployed.  I am getting this in my logs:

```
com.google.api.server.spi.WebApisUserService getCurrentUser: getCurrentUser: clientId     292824132082.apps.googleusercontent not allowed
```

Also getting:

```
 BackendService.getApiConfigs 400
```

when the app starts.

What can be causing this??

UPDATE:

My endpoints are working from a web app and mobile app with authentication.  However from the API explorer authentication fails...

Using 1.8.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I got this working was to delete all the discovery and rpc files and regenerate.  Now endpoints are being updated.

Comment: Yes, working now.  Thanks.  will accept as answer later...Think it was something to do with updating to 1.8.6 and objectify keys, which I see you saw my other questions.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your update, is your deployment successful now?